# Using one activity resources from other class

Tags: android, android-activity, android-resources

I have situation where I get the nearest location based on checking the distance between current lat and long

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        lat1=loc.getLatitude();
    lng1=loc.getLongitude();
           Com_Util.check_NearLoc(lat1,lng1);
    }
```

I update a static variable which contains the nearest place from the current location and display in a  text view showing the current location in all the activities. I am able to get the nearest place and was able to display it only during onCreate of an activity.

I need a text view showing the current location while using the app. I dont want a thread to be running all the time checking for the location change instead is there any way updating the textviews from the check_NearLoc function itself which is in a nonactivity class.

Comment: you can pass values from one activity to another using intent.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.. the function check_NearLoc(lat1,lng1) is not inside an activity in which i need to use resources and also I want to update the textview whenever location changes.